# bash scripts fail while trying to use list

Tags: bash, regular-expression, ip-address

I found a bash script to validate ip addresses here: 
http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/validating-ip-address-bash-script

When i try to run it I get the error :

```
 test.sh: line 22: syntax error: unexpected "(" (expecting "fi")
```

Line 22 looks like this:

```
  ip=($ip)
```

**Question**

1. Is this line supposed to be creating a list or array?
2. I've tried two different shells, and neither work.  tried:

   #!/bin/bash

and also

```
 #!/bin/sh
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Kindly paste the script here, so that the Question is not reliant on an external URL to be available.

Comment: What you say is line 22 is not actually line 22.

Comment: Also the way that script is written, it has to be named "valid_ip" in order to be run directly.  Otherwise you are supposed to source it and just use the `valid_ip` function with an argument like `valid_ip 10.10.10.10`

Comment: Either way there is no point for it to be in that script.  I recommend either removing the function and adding it to your bashrc or removing all the useless parts of the script (everything other than the function).

Comment: Since this is a bash script, if you run it like `sh test.sh`, you are using the wrong shell. Either use `bash test.sh` or give it execute permissions and the `#!/bin/bash` shebang and then use `/path/to/test.sh`

Comment: "Is this line supposed to be creating a list or array?" Since `bash` only has arrays, not lists, the question doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 3):

That:

```
test.sh: line 22: syntax error: unexpected "(" (expecting "fi")
```

is not an error message that `bash` reports. It is one that the Almquist shell and its derivatives like `dash` or busybox `sh` report though:

```
$ grep -z '(expecting' /bin/dash
%s unexpected (expecting %s)
```

`ash`-based shells don't support arrays, that script is meant for `bash` (3.2 or above) as the  `#!/bin/bash` she-bang indicates, though it looks more like a mix between `bash`, `zsh` and `ksh93` syntax if it's meant to check for quad-decimal IPv4 addresses where the parts are limited to 3 decimal digits (in `bash`, it would give some errors about `008.008.008.008` for instance).

With standard POSIX `sh` syntax which both `dash` and `bash` recognise, you could do instead:

```
valid_ip() (
  IFS=.
  set -o noglob
  set -- $1''
  [ "$#" -eq 4 ] || exit
  for i do
    case $i in
      ("" | *[!0-9]*) exit 1;;
    esac
    [ "$i" -le 255 ] || exit
  done
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
#!/bin/bash

ip=127.0.0.1

ip=($ip)

printf 'The first IP number is "%s"\n' "${ip[0]}"
```

If you're running this under `bash`, then you have something else wrong in your script relating to an `if` statement. If you're running this under `/bin/sh`, then it *should* fail as `sh` doesn't know about arrays.

I'd suggest you run your script through ShellCheck at https://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1):

**1)** *Is this line supposed to be creating a list or array?*

It's creating an array.  First it sets the IFS to `.` and then it says ip=($ip).  So if your `ip=10.11.12.13` your array would be `ip=([0]=10 [1]=11 [2]=12 [3]=13)`
Then it goes on to verify that each octet is less than 256.

**2)** *What shell should this use*

This script is definitely made for bash and therefore should be ran in bash.

**3)** *What is my issue*

The issue is that you have modified the script in some way that has caused a syntax error.  Please post the full script exactly as you are running it and we can try to figure it out.   Additionally as I said in my comment, you must name this script `valid_ip.sh`.  Failure to do such shouldn't cause your error but it will also make the script not work.

Comment: I didn't change the script.  i did a copy paste.  but if you still want me to paste it all here i will.

Comment: @glennjackman the second part of the script checks if the basename is valid_ip.  If not it doesn't do anything.  @dot if you didn't change anything how did you determine line 22?  Because line 22 in that script is `stat=$?` not `ip=($ip)` but my guess is that the `fi` just below that somehow got removed.

Comment: Also @glennjackman the function does modify the IFS but then changes it back although I guess that could be an issue if some operation where happening in the background at that exact moment?

Comment: @Jesse_b, quite right, my bad.